# MongoDB Embedded Documents / Documents with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, nosql

I've recently begun playing around with MongoDB on Rails through use of the MongoMapper gem.  I was wondering if there is some sort of way to have a class/object/collection be both a Document as well as an Embedded Document.  I want the same entity to be both included/embedded in other documents, and also be able to exist on its own as an object.

Is this possible?  Am I tackling this problem the wrong way?  Any discussion/advice would be greatly appreciated as resources on the web seem low for this stuff right now.

Comment: The general answer is no, but I think you may be approaching the problem in the wrong way. Can you say exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sure, so I have two Entities: Business and Person.  I want businesses to have people as an embedded document.  However, I want people to be their own document because they have associated entities as well.  

They both have their own show pages -- and are separate entities.  But for a matter of efficiency I would like people to be able to be stored as embedded documents for businesses.  

I understand this may require two "copies" of the same entity to exist.  I was planning on just writing an after_save callback to update associated references of people.  

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Probably easiest to store an array of references to the People objects in each business.

Comment: This isn't strictly possible because you would end up conflating associations with embedded associations, which you probably don't want. You could duplicate the references so that Business `has_many :people`, and `has_many :embedded_people` or something, but it'd be up to you to keep them in sync. Is it possible you are prematurely optimizing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar usecase and the solition was to have (using your entity names):

- a collection with People
- a embedded model BusinessPerson that `belongs_to_related :person`
- a collection with Businesses that `embeds_many :busiess_people`

The idea behind this was that I have extra fields in BusinessPerson that may not apply if the Person also run a different business. Let's say the role in that business, an email address or the share of it.

No you might say getting the business a person might look hard, but it isn't:

```
class Person
   def businesses
     Business.where('business_people._id' => self.id)
   end
end
```